# How to send value using achor tag in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, url, struts2, anchor

How to send value using anchor tag in Struts2 please give me an example and I know we can achieve this using `url` tag, but I want it using anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

The anchor  [`<s:a>` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/a-tag.html) in Struts2 as well as the other tags could be parametrized with the `<s:param>` tag. Just place param tag in the body of the anchor tag. For example

```
<s:a action="myaction"><s:param name="myparam" value="%{property}"/></s:a>
```

Comment: No actually I have done like this <a href="displayMails"><s:property value="subject" /></a>  along with this I need to pass message_id how can I do this please suggest

Comment: You have asked how to send a value using S2 anchor tag, right?

Comment: I don't understand what are you talking, I've said to you the answer on the above question.

Comment: I do not want use forms to send values I have an url link when I clicks that link I have to pass another value message_id

Comment: @user1712656 Edit your question, don't post code in comments.

Comment: <a href="displayMails"><s:property value="subject" /></a>

Comment: @user1712656 The code is unreadable, please edit the question and add the code with description after the EDIT: mark.

Answer (score 1):

Create it like any other parameterized link.

Personally, I prefer to use JSP EL:

```
<a href="displayMails?foo=${someActionProperty}">${subject}</a>
```

But if you insist on tags:

```
<a href="displayMails?foo=<s:property value='%{someActionProperty}'/>">
  <s:property value="%{subject}"/>
</a>
```

... To use the S2 action name in the HREF.

```
<a href="<s:url action='displayMails'/>?foo=${someActionProperty}">${subject}</a>
```

At this point we're back to having no idea why the S2 tag isn't what you actually want.