# Struts1 Link tag to Struts2 Anchor Tag; get the action parameter

Tags: java, struts2, anchor

**Short Question:** How do I get the action passed in the `AnchorTag`'s action when I am customising it?

**Long Question:**

I am doing a migration from Struts 1 to Struts 2 where we are using some custom tags. One of the customisations is in the `org.apache.struts.taglib.html.LinkTag`. This has been customised to add additional parameters. Please see below a sample tag in a particular jsp.

```
<shared:link page="/getItems.do?itemType=ItemA&amp;callingPage=Summary">
```

This link gets added with some additional parameters by the customisation resulting in the  below modified link.

```
/main/getItems.do?itemType=ItemA&callingPage=Summary&custAcctId=1041&customerName=name_mask
```

The customisation is done like below by overiding the `calculateURL` method

```
    public class MetaLinkTag extends LinkTag {
        /**
         * Return the complete URL to which this hyperlink will direct the user.
         *
         * @exception JspException if an exception is thrown calculating the value
         */
    protected String calculateURL() throws JspException {

        // Identify the parameters we will add to the completed URL
        Map params = RequestUtils.computeParameters
            (pageContext, paramId, paramName, paramProperty, paramScope,
             name, property, scope, transaction);
        params.put("custAcctId","1041");
        params.put("custAcctName","name_mask");
        String url = RequestUtils.computeURL(pageContext, forward, href,
                                              page, params, anchor, false);
        return url;
    }
}
```

I have identified that the `org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.AnchorTag` in struts 2 will have to be customised to do the equivalent in Struts2. So I replaced the jsp as follows

```
<shared:link action="/getItems.do?itemType=ItemA&amp;callingPage=Summary">
```

but I am not able to get the parameter list for adding the new parameters. Struts 1 does `RequestUtils.computeParameters` to get the parameters and then appends additional stuff to it.

How do I get the original list of parameters of the `AnchorTag` for Struts 2

**P.S:** If I get the parameters list, I am planning to override the setAction with the new customised parameters list. Hopefully that goes good. Sample code below

```
public class MetaLinkTag extends AnchorTag {

@Override
public void setAction(String action) {
    //String existingAction = GetExistingAction()
    //super.setAction(existingAction +"&custAcctId=1041&customerName=name_mask");
}
```

Comment: A lot of unnecessary code. Why not to use the anchor tag with the dynamically generated URL? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17951417/573032) answer for details.

Comment: Unfortunately, the additional parameters are dynamically built from a hidden parameter. So, I will not be able to use the dynamically generated url.

Answer (score 0):

Spent 30+ mins in thinking/writing this question and I found the answer when I came to the end of it. It was straight forward.

```java
public class MetaLinkTag extends AnchorTag {

  @Override
  public void setAction(String action) {
      super.setAction(action +"&custAcctId=1041&customerName=name_mask");
  }

}
```

I don't want to waste this effort in writing this question. Putting it out here in case it is useful for someone.

Comment: An even better way of doing it would be override the populateParams() method.

Comment: I think an even *better* way to do this would be with a custom JSP tag and avoid the lower-level Java programming.